# how do i loop numbers around a calendar in c++?

Tags: c++builder

I have been working on this program for hours and cannot find out how to make the numbers loop around after they hit saturday. They either go way passed it to the right or if i add and endl; they go up and down.

```
// This is how my output looks like (except they curve around they just go forever to the right:

Number of days: 31
Offset: 0
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Showing the output is not very helpful without also showing the code that is generating it, and showing what the output *should* look like instead.  If I had to guess, your loop code is not outputting a line break after each 7th day.

Answer (score 0):

This what you mean?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=31; i++) {
        cout << ((i<10) ? " " : "") << i << " ";
        if (i%7==0) cout << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28                                                                                                                                                                                                            
29 30 31
```

The % sign is the modulus operator. It gives the remainder of division. So every 7th day divided by 7 is going to have a remainder of zero. That's how you check where to put the line breaks.